# Android - Modifying layout values in XML

Tags: android, xml, size, android-actionbar

Is there a way to modify the value of a resource while assigning it in XML?

For example, this works fine:

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

But I would like to double this value as its width:

```
// this obviously doesn't work
android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize * 2"
```

Is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this programmatically.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourlayout);
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();

params.width *= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks.  If no one comes up with a way to do it in XML i'll use this

Comment: I'm not aware that you can do it in XML. This is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Matt I don't think XML allows for operations. The parameters in quotes are taken literally as a string.